# How to understand @Configuration

Tags: spring, configuration, dependency-injection

I'm new to Java config. I have a code like this. SomeDao has its own dependency, shouldn't we set the dependencies since we are doing new? 
Can someone please help me understand this code?

```
@Configuration
public class DAOConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "someDao")
    public SomeDao someDao() {
        return new SomeDao();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you familiar with how this is done in xml?  It is extremely similar to that.

Here is an example of `SomeDao` being configured with `Dep1` (via constructor injection) and `Dep2` (via setter injection) in xml:

```
<bean id="someDao" class="com.example.SomeDao">
  <constructor-arg ref="dep1"/>
  <property name="dep2" ref="dep2"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dep1" class="com.example.Dep1" />
<bean id="dep2" class="com.example.Dep2" />
```

This same example in JavaConfig would be configured as such:

```
@Configuration
public class DAOConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "someDao")
    public SomeDao someDao() {
        final SomeDao someDao = new SomeDao(dep1());
        someDao.setDep2(dep2());
        return someDao;
    }

    @Bean(name="dep1")
    public Dep1 dep1() {
        return new Dep1();
    }

    @Bean(name-"dep2")
    public Dep2 dep2() {
        return new Dep2();
    }
}
```

All three beans are still registered with the `ApplicationContext` too, so you can have all three of these beans autowired into another class, like so:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private SomeDao someDao;

    @Autowired
    private Dep1 dep1;

    //...some methods
}
```